Debian overwrite conflict
I want to generate debian packages, I am trying already with bloom. When I create a package that includes only the node the installation is successful and the node is created with all predicted functionality.
But when I add extra node and a launch file to trigger both of them, then during installation there is a conflict to overwrite the local '''/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/init.py''' which is also in package ros-humble-launch 1.0.6-1jammy (this is the ros debian).
Could you please explain me how to resolve?
I tried overwrite but ROS2 was broken and I had to reinstall.

what do you mean by generate debians?   ... Debian is the name of a linux distribution

https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Building-a-Custom-Debian-Package.html I mean this part I want to transfer the code easily from PC to another PC without creating package, build ... and goes on.

This sounds like your package has an incorrect installation rule or module name in you setup file. It should not be installing a file into opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/ but should be installing into
opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/<PACKAGENAME>/
With each package installing into it's own folder then there should be no conflicts.

data_files=[
('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
['resource/' + package_name]),
('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
    (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'launch'), glob(os.path.join('launch', '*launch.[pxy][yma]*'))),
],


I think it is defined correct here the installation path

You should note that the path you appear to be trying to install into doesn't match the output path. It looks like you package_name variable is not being set correctly and it's empty so the join drops it, so your subdirectory launch collides with the package named launch.
